# Sticky Footer Issue CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple sticky footer but when I use margin-bottom nothing happens. :(
Any help would be awesome! Here is the code.

```
<body>
<div class="main">
<center>
<img src="img/profpic.png" style="height:300.5px; width:auto; margin-top:75px; margin-bottom:30px;"/> <br/>
<span style="color:#FFF; font-size:69px;">Hi, $firstname</span> <br/>
<img src="img/button.jpg" style="height:111px; width:auto; margin-top:120px; margin-bottom:135px;"/> <br/>
<span style="color:#FFF; font-size:54px; ">Or Tap Here</span> <br/>
<!--Footer -->
<div style=" margin-bottom:10px; height:10px; width:100%; border-top:solid 1px white; color:#FFF; font-size:46px;">Happyfaxe</div>
</center>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin-bottom` adds space below an element, it doesn't reposition it to the bottom of the page.

Try adding this to your sticky footer div:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
```

Edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGRap/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`margin-bottom` just adds a buffer to the element it's applied to. Sticky footers are a bit tricky. It takes some special structuring to get it to work like you expect.

Here's a great article on how to do what you're wanting to do
[CSS-Tricks, Sticky footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

And Here's another doing the same thing:
[cssstickyfooter.com](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/html-code.html)